# How to setup Proxy in Karate config file

Tags: selenium, karate

I am using the following syntax in karate feature file and it works but I want to add this globally in karate config file so that I don't have to add in all of my feature file individually

```
* configure proxy = { uri: 'http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:8080', username: 'myuserid', password: 'xxxxxx' }
```

I need to know how we can add above globally in `karate-config.js` file

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [karate documentation](https://github.com/intuit/karate#managing-headers-ssl-timeouts-and-http-proxy) is quite comprehensive.

If you have any questions, it's pretty likely to find the answer there or in a related demo `.feature` file.

From the documentation:

> And if you need to set some of these 'globally' you can easily do so using the karate object in karate-config.js - for e.g. karate.configure('ssl', true).

So, I would try to put the following snippet in `karate-config.js`:

```
function() {
    var config = {
        BASE_URL:  'base url one,
        BASE_URL2: 'base url two'
    };
    karate.configure('proxy',  { uri: 'http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:8080', username: 'myuserid', password: 'xxxxxx' });
    return config;
}
```

Needless to say, that you can use `karate.env` property to configure your proxy on the base of your environment.

Comment: Thanks Peter for your reply. Yes I tried that karate.configure but it didnt work for me so I thought there may be some other way to resolve.

Comment: Are you sure that your `karate-config.js` gets picked up?

Comment: Yes as I have BASE URL is defined and it work when i use my feature file

Comment: Here is my config file please let me know if anything wrong, as BASE_URL is working fine

function() { 
 
 var config = {
  BASE_URL : 'https://myfirstURL',
  BASE2_URL : 'https://mysecondURL',
  
         karate.configure('proxy',  { uri: 'http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:8080', username: 'myuserid', password: 'xxxxxx' });
  
  
 
 };
 return config;

Comment: Looks like you put the `karate.configure` at the wrong place - updated my answer.

Comment: It works.. Yayyyy

Thank you peter for your help and quick response. Thanks

Comment: Great and it would be better if you accept my answer.